# Why am I getting a retain cycle from passing weak self in to a static function's closure?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

My `AchievementViewController` does not get released from memory unless I comment out the function below

```
    NetworkConnection.achievementList(for: -1) { [weak self] response in
        guard let sections = response.object as? [AchievementListSection] else {
            return print("Network failure")
        }
        self?.sections = sections
        self?.configureCollectionView()
    }
```

The definition for this function is below where at present we just use a delayed async call to send a stubbed response.

```
static func achievementList(for identifier: Int64, responseHandler: RequestResponseClosure?) {
    let stubResponse = ResponseObject(object: AchievementListSection.exampleList as NSArray, code: .success)
    let randomDelayMilliseconds = Int(arc4random_uniform(1000))
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(randomDelayMilliseconds)) {
        responseHandler?(stubResponse)
    }
}
```

Where exactly is self being retained to create a cycle here? It's passed in to the NetworkConnection closure as a `weak` reference and in turn when this closure is passed to `DispatchQueue` I would expect it to release after the delay has passed.

Comment: The fact that you capture `weak self` in the closure should prevent retain cycles regardless how `achievementList` is implemented. Are you sure that closure is the problematic one, and the problem doesn't start elsewhere?

Comment: @Cristik As sure as I can be unfortunately. If I comment out this function the viewcontroller is released. Without commenting it out the viewcontroller is never released.

Comment: try comment self?.configureCollectionView() to see mb it's the problem

Comment: @Kstin Ah it does thank you. I've been barking up the wrong tree. Feel free to put that as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try comment this line

```
self?.configureCollectionView()
```

mb it's the problem, because `[weak self]` is enough for fix retain in this closure